# Calculating Lift of a closed-wing drone

Tags: wing, lift, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, nasa, amateur-experimental

A group of students and I are designing a theoretical closed-wing drone and need to calculate lift based on the NASA lift equation. We've designed fixed-wing aircraft before and when it came to finding the co-efficient of lift for the airfoil, we just used the NACA charts. Since the aircraft will be closed wing this time around, we are not entirely sure how to go about this. We are very amateur, so I know we are likely missing very obvious things. Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Comment: Have you tried AVL?

Comment: @Jimmy I tried googling it, but the page for a consulting firm came up.

Comment: Athena Vortex Lattice. You probably want to read up on what vortex lattice is and how it computes. The AVL manual is also good.

Comment: @Jimmy Thank you! This looks like it might be just what we need!